# Bind right corner of the next badge progress bar to the badge block border

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, badges, badge-progress

On most cases (screen width) the right corner of the next badge progress bar is aligned with bronze badge block. But sometimes when newest badge and next badge can not fit into single line, the right corner of the progress bar is located more to the left than necessary.

> [image: Animation]

I'm suggesting always use the same vertical position for right corner of bronze badge count and progress bar:

> [image: Next badge increase width]